# Android - Google maps API not showing maps

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps

I am using google maps API with my android app and its not showing anything but blank maps.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOngg.png) is the screen shot.

I have obtained an API key from google developers and pasted into google_maps_api.xml both in debug and release version.

```
<string name="google_maps_key" translatable="false" templateMergeStrategy="preserve">
        AIzaSyCAiL844hgfM2S_kDApCrITIzj-S5wgBzA
</string>
```

I registered my app on google developers account also [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLQQY.jpg)

I did not do anything with the maps but just selected the MapsActivity from wizard.

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

Comment: Is `android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"` added as a permission in your manifest?

Comment: Problem is create MAP_KEY Please follow this link and create working for me.(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start)

Comment: @VishalPatolia kindly read the question. I do have MAPS key

Comment: @Slim I did have permissions. I have updated the question with permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few reasons why your Google Map is not showing nothing.

Youu have to put something like this A5:1A:89:84:A9:5C:B7:13:6D:7C:28:20:C5:65:A4:F4:97:E4:98:99;co.mipackage.example. The number, in my case A5:1A:89:84:A9:5C:B7:13:6D:7C:28:20:C5:65:A4:F4:97:E4:98:99 have to be the assigned number for your computer, so you have to see if it is correct. The path of the package have to be correct too.

Comment: Can you explain? how?

Answer (score 0):

Well thank you everyone for suggestions but I have solved my issue.

Problem was with my Package name it was com.example.picturetrackerapp in my project but was registered as com.example.picturetracker on google developers account. I changed it and my problem solved

Comment: Great!. Can you choose my answer, I wrote "The path of the package have to be correct too" thanks in advance.